# How can I add a square with a text next to a chart (in Python/Plotly)

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly.graph-objects

I prepared a page with charts, using graph object library. I'm trying to add a short information about the each chart on this screen, e.g. "Service Level", next to a chart (on left side).

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKvbF.png)

I would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: In this example from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#styling-and-coloring-annotations), the orange box will be helpful.